# Exceptional Lines (Blowing Up)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please refer to the image given below (Book: Singular Points of Plane Curves by C.T.C. Wall).

**Example 3.3.1:**

For the *third blow up*, how do we come to the conclusions that $E_{0}$ is $x_{3}=0$ and the transform of $E_{1}$ does not meet the domain of this chart?

[image]

[image]

**Working for the final blow up.**

For the last blow up, I have two options (1) $(x_{5},y_{5})=(x_{6},x_{6}y_{6})$  or (2) $(x_{5},y_{5})=(x_{6}y_{6},y_{6})$.

Option (1) gives the exceptional curve $E_{5}: x_{6}=0$, transform of $E_{3}$ is not in this chart, transform of $E_{4}$ is $y_{6}=0$  and the transform of the curve is $C^{(6)}: y_{6}=1$.

Option (2) gives the exceptional curve $E_{5}: y_{6}=0$, transform of $E_{3}$ is $x_{6}=0$, transform of $E_{4}$ is not in this chart and the transform of the curve is $C^{(6)}: x_{6}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the blow-up of the point $(0,0)\in \mathbb{A}^2$ is given by

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\{([u:v],(x,y))\in \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{A}^2\mid  uy=vx\}&\to& \mathbb{A}^2\\
([u:v],(x,y)) & \mapsto & (x,y)\end{array}$$

The exceptional divisor is then equal to $\mathbb{P}^1\times (0,0)$ and you have two charts on the blow-up: either $u\not=0$ or $v\not=0$. Choosing respectively $u=1$ and $v=1$ gives $y=vx$ and $x=uy$, so this gives two maps 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\{([u:v],(x,y))\in \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{A}^2\mid  uy=vx\}&\to& \mathbb{A}^2\\
([1:v],(x,vx)) & \mapsto & (x,vx)\\
([u:1],(uy,y)) & \mapsto & (uy,y)\end{array}$$
and you can see then the blow-up in two charts: $(a,b)\mapsto (ab,b)$ or $(a,b)\mapsto (a,ab)$ from $\mathbb{A}^2$ to $\mathbb{A}^2$. In the first one, you remove the strict transform of $y=0$ and in the second one you remove the strict transform of $x=0$. Moreover, the exceptional curve is given by $b=0$ and $a=0$ respectively.

Looking at the text that you give, the author says that he has $(x_2,y_2)=(x_3y_3,y_3)$. Hence, the strict transform of $y_2=0$ is removed from the chart and the exceptional divisor is $y_3=0$.

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening in the last (6th) blow up. This is page 48 of the book? The link for the book is http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il%2F~dnovikov%2FIntroSing0910%2FWallBook.pdf&ei=g3FzU5DoCITEkgWrq4HgBw&usg=AFQjCNGCz5unMQqrTUox6o5_7_juADKXOQ&bvm=bv.66699033,d.dGI                                    I am a bit confused. If for my 6th blow up, I use $(x_{5},y_{5})=(x_{6},x_{6}y_{6})$, then does it mean that $x_{5}=0$? That is, has $E_{3}$ been removed from the chart?

Comment: It it said that the curve has equation $x_5=y_5$, so it intersects the two curves $x_5=0$ and $y_5=0$ (draw a picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$), then when you blow-up the exceptional divisor is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the strict transform of the three curves $x_5=0$, $y_5=0$ and $x_5=y_5$ are disjoint, but each of them meet the last exceptional divisor. In each of your charts you do not see one curve. If you want to see all, just make a change of coordinates $(x_5',y_5')=(x_5+2y_5,y_5)$ before.

Answer (score 1):

At stage 2, $E_1$ is given by $y_2 = 0 $ and the strict transform of $E_0$ is given by $x_2 = 0$.

The blow up is given by $x_2 = x_3 y_3, y_2 = y _3.$

The strict transform of $E_1$ at stage $3$ is given by the Zariski closure of points
where $y_2 = 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$.  But in the given chart for the third blow-up,
if $y_2 = 0$ then $y_3 = 0$ and so also $x_2 = 0$.  Thus the strict transform of $E_1$ is disjoint from this chart.

The strict transform of $E_0$ is given by the Zariski closure of points where $x_2 = 0$ but $y_2 \neq 0$, which in the chart for the third blow up becomes $x_3 y_3 = 0$ but $y_3 \neq 0$, or equivalently, $x_3 = 0, y_3 \neq 0$.  The Zariski closure of this locus is just the locus where $x_3 = 0.$

Comment: Could you then please explain what is happening in the final blow up? This is page 48. I have updated the question to include this page. For the final blow up, if I either use the transformation $(x_{5},y_{5})=(x_{6},x_{6}y_{6})$ or $(x_{5},y_{5})=(x_{6}y_{6},y_{6})$, then does this mean that either $E_{3}$ or $E_{4}$ is removed from the final chart?

Comment: Dear Radz, I don't have time to read through the details.  Have you tried working it out for yourself, one chart at a time?  It is just a matter of patience and taking care with notation/labelling.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E, using what you had written earlier, I did verify the results of the book. My only problem is with the last (6th) blow. In particular, with the conclusion "This produces a final exceptional curve $E_{5}$ which meets each of $E_{3}$, $E_{4}$ and $C^{(6)}$ transversely,...". In the book, the 5th blow up produces the following: the exceptional curves are $E_{3}: x_{5}=0$, $E_{4}: y_{5}=0$ and the strict transform of the curve is $C^{(5)}: x_{5}=y_{5}$. Could you explain what I am then doing wrong for the final blow up? I have included the working in the original question.